# RVM - Common gems in all gem sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm using RVM and Gemsets to manage my Ruby project environments, I keep an `.rvmrc` file on each project directory in order to get a different Gemset (using `rvm use --create 1.9.3@<project_name>`). Everything works well in that manner, but:

For some reason though, when I use `rvm use <ruby_version>@<gemset_name>` and then `gem list` I get a mixture of the correct gems (the ones which indeed - have been installed in my project), as well as some other gems which are definitely not related.

Any idea what may causing this? maybe there's a 'default' gemset which if I accidentally installed some gems on it, It'll include them in all of my gemsets?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, found my answer in here - **[Interpreter global gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/global/)**:

*RVM provides (>= 0.1.8) a @global gemset per ruby interpreter.
Gems you install to the @global gemset for a given ruby are available to all other gemsets you create in association with that ruby.
This is a good way to allow all of your projects to share the same installed gem for a specific ruby interpreter installation.*

Comment: you should accept your anser so people can quickly see it is the right one

Comment: Can only do it in two days :/